# Изменение активного пункта меню при прокрутке страницы vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Работаю с vuetify.При нажатии таба, страница прокручивается до якоря. Нужно сделать обратное. При прокрутки страницы, у таба, соответствующего заголовку страницы, появляется активный класс

Как можно подсвечивать пункт меню в зависимости от прокрутки страницы. В vuetify есть директива `v-intersect`, которая показывает, находится ли объект в области видимости. Если кто сталкивался с подобным или примерно понимает, напишите пожалуйста ваше решение с помощью этой директивы или может другим способом

Ссылка на пример
https://codepen.io/kalorave/pen/zYKBjNK?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать подсветку через `v-bind:class`

Якорю добавить условие на добавление класса, в условии указываем id элемента

```
<v-card-title id="anchor-home" v-bind:class="{ active: activeAnchor == '#anchor-home' }">
```

`v-bind:class` добавить для каждого заголовка заменяя id в условии на id элемента

В функции `goToAnchor` сохраняем переданный параметр якоря

```
goToAnchor(anchor) {
      this.activatedAnchorFlag = true;
      this.activeAnchor = anchor;
      this.$vuetify.goTo(anchor);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.activatedAnchorFlag = false;
        this.activeAnchor = null;
      }, 1000);
}
```